# MySQL how to check if value starts with letter and ends with a number?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to show specific data where all the values start with a letter and ends with a number in the city of cansas only.

What my table looks like:

hotelroom

```
pID     |name       |  city |   key
--------------------------------------------
543     |H. Stein   |Cansas   | 16Z004
542     |Z. Francis |Cansas   | Z10-30
642     |Q. Snake   |Cansas   | Z10-25
645     |P. Brown   |Kentucky | Z10-40
```

What I want:

```
pID     |name       |  city |   key
--------------------------------------------
542     |Z. Francis |Cansas |   Z10-30
642     |Q. Snake   |Cansas |   Z10-25
```

What I tried and did not work:

```
SELECT * FROM hotelroom
WHERE city LIKE '%Cansas%' AND
key LIKE '^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ].*[0123456789]$'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [REGEXP](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-regular-expression-regexp.aspx), `WHERE fields REGEXP regex_string`. Also, you don't have to write all of the alphabet letter, you could just write it like `[a-zA-Z]`.

> To be specific: a range is a contiguous series of characters, from low
>   to high, in the ASCII character set.[101] For example, [z-a] is not a
>   range because it's backwards. The range [A-z] matches both uppercase
>   and lowercase letters, but it also matches the six characters that
>   fall between uppercase and lowercase letters in the ASCII chart: [, \,
>   ], ^, _, and '.

https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch32_08.htm

```
SELECT * FROM hotelroom
WHERE city LIKE '%Cansas%' AND
key REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z].*[0-9]$'
```

Also,

> I want to show specific data where all the values start with a letter
>   and ends with a number in the city of cansas only.

If you only want to get the result from the city of Cansas, you don't have to use `LIKE`. If you're using `LIKE`, it will also match `Cansas2` city or anything that has `Cansas` as it's substring.

You could just use [equals (=) operator](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).

```
SELECT * FROM hotelroom
WHERE city = 'Cansas' AND
key REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z].*[0-9]$'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `RLIKE` instead of `LIKE`

```
SELECT * FROM hotelroom
WHERE city LIKE '%Cansas%' AND
key RLIKE '^[a-zA-z].*[0-9]$'
```

The documentation you can find here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp